# Bad Request Exception in Jetty while its working fine in WildFly

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jetty, jax-rs

HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /demo-ws/api/exam/save. Reason:

Bad arguments passed to public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.sandag.controller.RulesetController.saveRuleset(com.sandag.model.Exam)( org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException org.jboss.resteasy.spi.BadRequestException: Could not find message body reader for type: class com.sandag.model.Exam of content type: application/json )

Controller

```
@POST
@Path("/save")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response saveExam(@RequestBody Exam exam) {
    Response response = null;
    try{
        response = status( new Gson().toJson(examService.saveExam(exam)));
    }catch(Exception ex){
        Log.error("Exam Controller : saveExam", ex);
    }
    return response;
}
```

JSON Data:

```
{ 
 "id": 23, 
 "name": "Exam 1" 
}
```

The Request works fine with the above data when WildFly Server is used. But When Jetty is used I am getting the above mentioned error. Can anyone point me in the right direction..? **Using Spring and JAX-RS for Rest-API.**

**UPDATE:**

WildFly Version 10.1.0

Jetty Version 9.3.11

Comment: What specific version of Jetty?  Saying "Jetty 9" is only saying "Any major version of Jetty that supports Servlet 3.1" (of which there are 5 major versions)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Updated with the exact versions.